# Badly conditioned matrix for some boundary points

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have a nonlinear coupled second order differential equation which is going to be generated by solving the Euler Lagrange equation for which those differential equations correspond to `eq01` and `eq02`. I'm going to use finite-difference method to solve these equations, i.e., I'll set up the sparse matrix which when solved will provide the correction needed for the initial guess (indicated by `init[0]`) of the solution to the differential equations. After obtaining the sparse matrix, I solve it using Newton's method. The code below is divided into these three steps for clarity.

The boundary conditions of the differential equations are `ui`,`uf`,`zi`,`zf`. The constraint is `ui < uf` while `zf = 10^-1` is fixed. My plan is to run different values of `ui` and `zi` for a fixed `uf` (the difference of `uf` from `zf` is I'll eventually pick another value for `uf` then run different values of `ui` and `zi` again but `zf` is completely fixed for all these). If I choose say, `uf = 7` then `ui = 5` and `zi = 8`, everything works fine.

However, when I choose `ui` or `zi` to be far away (or both are far away) from `uf` I encounter an error from `LinearSolve`. For example, `ui = 2` (a bit far from `uf = 7`) and `zi = 8` OR `ui = 6` and `zi = 15` (a bit far from `uf = 7`) OR `ui = 2` and `zi = 15` (both are a bit far from `uf = 7`). I understand that I can't just take any arbitrary values for these parameters, but at least I want to have some considerable amount of range to run these parameters, e.g. maybe `zi=1` to `zi=20`.

````
(*Equation setup*)
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
u0 = 20;
m = (1/u[x] - 1/u0);
f = 1 - m z[x]^(d + 1);
L = (Sqrt[-f u'[x]^2 - 2 u'[x] z'[x] + 1]/z[x]^d) + (d - 1) (z'[x]/z[x]^d);(*Lagrangian*)
eq1 = EulerEquations[L, u[x], x];
eq2 = EulerEquations[L, z[x], x];
s = Solve[{eq1, eq2} /. d -> 3, {u''[x], z''[x]}][[1]] // Simplify;
eq01 = u''[x] - s[[1, 2]];
eq02 = z''[x] - s[[2, 2]];

(*Finite difference method: Sparse matrix setup*)
n = 200; (*grid points*)
h = (b - a)/(n - 1); (*step size*)
a = 10^-8; (*a & b are the domain*)
b = 10^-1;
ui = 2; (*ui, uf, zi, zf are the boundary conditions*)
uf = 7;
zi = 15;
zf = 10^-1;
rule = {u''[x] -> ((u[i + 1] - 2 u[i] + u[i - 1])/h^2), u'[x] -> ((u[i + 1] - u[i - 1])/(2 h)), u[x] -> u[i], z''[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - 2 z[i] + z[i - 1])/h^2), z'[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - z[i - 1])/(2 h)), z[x] -> z[i]};
resid1 = h^2 eq01 /. rule;
resid2 = h^2 eq02 /. rule;
parresid1 = {D[resid1, u[i - 1]], D[resid1, z[i - 1]], D[resid1, u[i]], D[resid1, z[i]], D[resid1, u[i + 1]], D[resid1, z[i + 1]]};
parresid2 = {D[resid2, u[i - 1]], D[resid2, z[i - 1]], D[resid2, u[i]], D[resid2, z[i]], D[resid2, u[i + 1]], D[resid2, z[i + 1]]};
mat = {parresid1, parresid2};
sparseresidual = Normal[SparseArray[Table[Band[{2 (i - 2) + 1, 2 (i - 2) + 1}] -> {mat}, {i, 2, n - 1}]]];
sparse = Join[{Join[{1}, ConstantArray[0, 2 n - 1]]}, {Join[{0, 1}, ConstantArray[0, 2 n - 2]]}, sparseresidual, {Join[ConstantArray[0, 2 n - 2], {1, 0}]}, {Join[ConstantArray[0, 2 n - 1], {1}]}];

(*Solving the nonlinear system of equations through Newton's method*)
m = 30; (*Number of iterations*)
init[0] = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {Join[{ui}, Reverse[Table[((ui - uf)/(b - a)) (i - a) + uf, {i, a + h, b - h, h}]], {uf}], Join[{zi}, Reverse[Table[((zi - zf)/(b - a)) (i - a) + zf, {i, a + h, b - h, h}]], {zf}]}] // Flatten;
For[j = 0, j <= m, j++, residuals = Table[{{resid1}, {resid2}} /. i -> j, {j, 2, n - 1}] // Flatten;
DFxmat = sparse /. {u[i_] :> init[j][[2 i - 1]], z[i_] :> init[j][[2 i]]}; 
Residvec = Join[{0, 0}, residuals /. {u[i_] :> init[j][[2 i - 1]], z[i_] :> init[j][[2 i]]}, {0, 0}]; 
init[j + 1] = init[j] + 0.7 LinearSolve[N[DFxmat, 30], N[-Residvec, 30]] // Flatten] // AbsoluteTiming
finalsolution = init[j]

LinearSolve::luc: Result for LinearSolve of badly conditioned matrix {{1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<390>>},{0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<390>>},<<7>>,{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,132.1319891,0.9584233208,0.01115998895,-2.012128375,<<390>>},<<390>>} may contain significant numerical errors.
LinearSolve::luc: Result for LinearSolve of badly conditioned matrix {{1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<390>>},{0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<390>>},<<7>>,{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,105.0729581,0.9683577215,0.007541112841,-2.008287291,<<390>>},<<390>>} may contain significant numerical errors.
LinearSolve::luc: Result for LinearSolve of badly conditioned matrix {{1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<390>>},{0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<390>>},<<7>>,{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1.083697194*10^9,189.6354636,1.494207434*10^6,-249300.3218,<<390>>},<<390>>} may contain significant numerical errors.
General::stop: Further output of LinearSolve::luc will be suppressed during this calculation.
```
````

Comment: Bad conditioning is not a Mathematica problem. Mathematica tells you that your matrix is badly conditioned, but it says something about your problem and the choices you made when modeling it numerically.

Comment: You could try machine precision with the 'LinearSolve[...., Method -> Pardiso]'

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
LinearSolve[DFxmat // N, -Residvec // N, Method -> "Pardiso"]
```

works. Pardiso can solve close to singular systems and it does in this case, but it's for machine precision only.